# Far From The Madding Crowd

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm having trouble understanding the following paragraph from Far From The Madding Crowd.

> Had the wife now but gone no further. Yet, perhaps, under the harrowing circumstances, to speak out was the one wrong act which can be better understood, if not forgiven in her, than the right and politic one, her rival being now but a corpse. All the feeling she had been betrayed into showing she drew back to herself again by a strenuous effort of self-command.

1: *Had the wife now but gone no further*
Does this mean "If only the wife had not gone further."?

2: *to speak out was the one wrong act which can be better understood, if not forgiven in her, than the right and politic one, her rival being now but a corpse.*
What does he mean by this?

Comment: I assume this is Bathsheba after opening Fanny's coffin. (1) Yes, I assume that is the meaning. (2) 'One can understand why she spoke out, even though it was a wrong and unwise thing to do.'

Comment: Thanks Kate.  What does this have to do with rest of the paragraph : her rival being now but a corpse.

Comment: Are you actually reading the book? It's many years since I read it and I don't have a copy to hand. Presumably it refers to the fact that, as Fanny is dead, nothing Bathsheba does or says can harm her any more.